# Convert SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY to built-in VARRAY (to create function-based index)

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle18c, varray

*Oracle 18c:*

I can get `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY` values from `SDO_GEOMETRY` objects:

```
create table test_table (shape sdo_geometry);

insert into test_table (shape) values (sdo_geometry('linestring(10 20, 30 40, 50 60)'));
insert into test_table (shape) values (sdo_geometry('linestring(70 80, 90 100)'));
insert into test_table (shape) values (sdo_geometry('linestring(110 120, 130 140, 150 160, 170 180)'));

select
    (shape).sdo_ordinates as sdo_ordinate_array
from
    test_table


SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY
------------------
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(70, 80, 90, 100)
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f38ba8af6a9bbc97585cf603e74774c5)

For what it's worth, this is what the definition of the `MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY` type looks like in SQL Developer:

```
create or replace TYPE SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY AS VARRAY(1048576) OF NUMBER
```

---

Using a function, I want to convert the `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAYs` to the built-in `VARRAY` datatype.

Reason: I want to experiment with storing the ordinates in a non-spatial Function-Based Index. If I understand correctly, only built-in datatypes are supported by FBIs, not Oracle-supplied types or abstract datatypes like `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY` or `SDO_GEOMETRY`.

- [Idea: Support function-based indexes on Abstract datatypes](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16838971/#Comment_16838971).
- Function-based **spatial** indexes don't help me in this case either, since I want to utilize the index using the SELECT list of a query, not in a spatial operation in the WHERE clause. [Why can't a spatial index be invoked by the SELECT list, yet a non-spatial index can?](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499770/why-cant-a-spatial-index-be-invoked-by-the-select-list-yet-a-non-spatial-index-can)

For example, if I were to try to create the following FBI, it would fail:

```
create index sdo_ordinates_idx on test_table ((shape).sdo_ordinates);
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 12 in command -
create index sdo_ordinates_idx on test_table ((shape).sdo_ordinates)
Error report -
ORA-02327: cannot create index on expression with datatype ADT     ADT=Abstract Datatype
02327. 00000 -  "cannot create index on expression with datatype %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create an index on a non-indexable
           expression.
*Action:   Change the column datatype or do not create the index on an
           expression whose datatype is one of  VARRAY, nested table, object,
           LOB, or  REF.
```

So I can't create an FBI on `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY`. But I'm hoping I can convert the ordinates to a regular `VARRAY` instead and make an FBI on those values.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to convert `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAYs` to built-in `VARRAYs`? (for the purpose of a function-based index)

I would prefer to store the ordinates as a proper `VARRAYs`, rather than convert them to text. Reason: I believe the `SDO_GEOMETRY` constructor only accepts array values, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> the definition of the `MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY` type looks like in SQL Developer:
>
> ```sql
> create or replace TYPE SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY AS VARRAY(1048576) OF NUMBER
> ```

and then ask:

> Is there a way to convert `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY`s to built-in `VARRAY`s? (for the purpose of a function-based index)

It is already a `VARRAY`, you do not need to convert it.

#### However

The error message states:

> ```
> Error report -
> ORA-02327: cannot create index on expression with datatype ADT     > ADT=Abstract Datatype
> 02327. 00000 -  "cannot create index on expression with datatype %s"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to create an index on a non-indexable
>            expression.
> *Action:   Change the column datatype or do not create the index on an
>            expression whose datatype is one of VARRAY, nested table, object,
>            LOB, or  REF.
> ```

In the `action` section it specifically states that you cannot create an index on an expression whose datatype is one of `VARRAY` or nested table. So what you are asking is impossible; you cannot create an index on a `VARRAY`.

#### Finally

You state:

> I would prefer to store the ordinates as a proper VARRAYs, rather than convert them to text. Reason: I believe the SDO_GEOMETRY constructor only accepts array values, not text.

Looking at the source:

```sql
select text
from   all_source
where  type  = 'TYPE'
and    owner = 'MDSYS'
and    name  = 'SDO_GEOMETRY'
ORDER BY line
```

The `MDSYS_SDO_GEOMETRY` type has the constructors:

> ```
>    ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION SDO_GEOMETRY(wkt IN CLOB,
>      srid IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
>      DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE,
>    ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION SDO_GEOMETRY(wkt IN VARCHAR2,
>      srid IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
>      DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE,
>    ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION SDO_GEOMETRY(wkb IN BLOB,
>      srid IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
>      DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE,
>    ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION SDO_GEOMETRY(input_clob IN clob,
>      auxiliary_info IN varchar2, crs IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
>      RETURN SELF AS RESULT DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE,
>    ADD CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION SDO_GEOMETRY(input_vchar IN varchar2,
>      auxiliary_info IN varchar2, crs IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
>      RETURN SELF AS RESULT DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE
>    CASCADE
> ```

None of those constructors take a `VARRAY` argument. They all take strings (`VARCHAR2` or `CLOB`) except for one that takes a `BLOB`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=121753c49acfb39d4d1134059fb42c5b)*

Comment: Thanks. What I had in mind was: constructing an SDO_GEOEMTRY via it's attributes: `SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))`. I had planned on using a `VARRAY` in place of `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)`. I suppose there isn't a separate constructor function for that technique. Do you concur?

Comment: @User1974 [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-constructors.htm#SPATL501) does not list any constructors like that and neither does the source.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it's missing from the docs too. But it does seem to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8dd0dff5edc070dc03c5a26b6a749de. I've asked the Oracle Spatial team to add it to the docs: [Idea: Add info to SDO_GEOMETRY Constructors docs (construct via object type/attributes)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499812/idea-add-info-to-sdo-geometry-constructors-docs-construct-via-object-type-attributes).